# Grails custom ErrorController catch an exception but property request.exception is null

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-controller

My application works on grails 2.3.1. Some days ago I noticed strange behaviour of error controller. Grails calls error controller but request.exception is null. It seems this happened after application was updated from grails 2.2.x to 2.3.x and we start using async controllers. 
My controller:

```
package grailsapp

import static grails.async.Promises.task

class MyController {
    def controllerAction(ActionCommand command) {
        task {
            // Controller code
        }
    }
}
```

Moreover, it happens only if controller code contains difficult calculations, which takes a long time(about 30 sec).

I've tried to run code without grails async and it works perfect. 
Also tried wrap code within task with try\catch – nothing changed, catch section haven't caught anything.

```js
package grailsapp

import static grails.async.Promises.task

class MyController {
    def controllerAction(ActionCommand command) {
        task {
            try{
                // Controller code              
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace()
                // Nothing caught here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tried wrap whole action method body – the same result.

```
package grailsapp

import static grails.async.Promises.task

class MyController {
    def controllerAction(ActionCommand command) {
        try{
            task {
                // Controller code
            }               
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace()
            // Nothing caught here
        }
    }
}
```

Could someone help and explain why it happens?

Comment: Do you have any stacktrace?